# Convert getXml() to InputStream for SAX Parser

Tags: android, xml, inputstream

I get file from assets.

```
InputStream asset = packageResources.getAssets().open("some.xml");
```

And I have **InputStream** but when I use

```
packageResources.getXml(appFilterResId);
```

I have **XmlResourceParser** but I need **InputStream**.
Any idea how do that?

UPDATE

```
try {
    XMLReader xmlReader = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser()
            .getXMLReader();
    // create a SAXXMLHandler
    SAXXMLHandler saxHandler = new SAXXMLHandler(manager, packName);
    // store handler in XMLReader
    xmlReader.setContentHandler(saxHandler);
    // the process starts
    xmlReader.parse(new InputSource(xmlInputStream));
    // get the `Employee list`
    icons = saxHandler.getIcons();

} catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.d("XML", "SAXXMLParser: parse() failed");
}
```

Here:

```
xmlReader.parse(new InputSource(xmlInputStream));
```

Need **InputStream**

Comment: @pskink question updated

Comment: So place your xml data in assets folder, whats wrong with that?

Comment: @pskink File is not in assets, is in xml :/

Comment: why? why in res/xml ?

Comment: @pskink Default have in other apps

Comment: so write thin adapter between XmlResourceParser and  ContentHandler

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way if you looking to get xml in inputstream by r.id ..

```
 InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.xml.appxml);
```

**Update** : I tried in my sample app and its works fine . this is the xml in my assests folder app.xml

```
<stuff> hello </stuff>
```

Here the xml parser code :

```
    XMLReader reader = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser()
                .getXMLReader();         

     class myhanlder implements ContentHandler { //this is ur SAXXMLHandler class .. not sure u implmented which handler..

             public myhanlder() {super(); }
                     public void  getIcon() { System.out.println(" ICON " ); }
          @Override  //other Override  methods impl ..
           // ...
           // ..
            //..
        };

            myhanlder handler = new myhanlder();
        reader.setContentHandler(handler);    
        InputStream in =  this.getResources().openRawResource(R.xml.app);
            reader.parse(new InputSource(in));
        handler.getIcon() ;
```

Comment: you cannot have the same file both in res/xml and assets folder

Comment: @Neha I get that file from other app by `packageResources = manager.getResourcesForApplication(packName);`

Comment: @KrisGroove So u mean to say trying to access the other app xml file, and when u do this packageResource.getAssets().open("xml") its works but when u try to get like this : packageResource.openRawResource(xml.id) its not works.. are u sure that xml file resides in res/xml folder of other app. ? Check if inputstream from openRawresource is null or not!!